# laravel 9 auth dropdown menu don't show

Tags: css, laravel

I am using laravel 9 UI auth.
When login in and I click the user name,
it should show a dropdown menu let me logout,
but the dropdown menu don't show

and it works properly in mobile (responsive) view

createPopper.js:110 Popper: CSS "margin" styles cannot be used to apply padding between the popper and its reference element or boundary. To replicate margin, use the `offset` modifier, as well as the `padding` option in the `preventOverflow` and `flip` modifiers.

```
setOptions @ createPopper.js:110
createPopper4 @ createPopper.js:215
_createPopper @ dropdown.js:240
show @ dropdown.js:138
toggle @ dropdown.js:120
(anonymous) @ dropdown.js:445
handler @ event-handler.js:118
```

'''''''

```
<!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto ">
              <!-- Authentication Links -->
              @guest
                  @if (Route::has('login'))
                      <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                      </li>
                  @endif

                  @if (Route::has('register'))
                      <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                      </li>
                  @endif
              @else
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
                      <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle " href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                          {{ Auth::user()->name }}
                      </a>

                      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-ende background-color-blues " aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">

                        {{--                    --}}
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                             onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                           document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                              {{ __('Logout') }}
                          </a>

                          <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
                              @csrf
                          </form>
                      </div>
                  </li>
              @endguest
          </ul>
```

''''''''''

I tried adding class    margin:0     ,
in different places but it doesn't work

Comment: Show the entire html of the menu/dropdown. This time, I would work around it: it's tailwind, in the mobile version it works, so make that mobile part work on the bigger screens. This is why you need to show the (blade) html

Comment: This is not my code, but the original laravel code